# Are there any regularly-scheduled special events happening at the Sounion temple (near Athens) in Greece?

Tags: greece, events, history, temples

Since sea surrounds the temple, it would be better to go when the weather is sweet, but is there anything special happening on that temple, which makes it better to visit at that time than in any random time?

[image]

---

Edit:

I am not really asking about whether it would be better to go on sweet weather or not, I am asking for any special events that have to do with the temple for example, or a festival nearby!

Comment: You are right, Poseidon might be moody!

Comment: Yeah but that seems as mountain with no sea nearby @pnuts. But your point is so true, I remember visiting the Great Pyramid and it was foggy and dark and we saw it from the bus rising like a dark blob and OH MY GOD what is this? And when we approached it we saw it was the Pyramid. Unique experience! ;)

Comment: Hmm I see @pnuts...I think that last comment should be posted as an answer! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed. According to [GreekReporter.com](http://greece.greekreporter.com/2016/09/23/sounion-half-marathon-at-the-ancient-temple-of-poseidon/):

> A new half marathon race, the Poseidon Challenge, will be held for the first time on October 2 at the southest part of Attica, at Sounio Cape. The race will link the Temple of Poseidon with the ancient theatre of Thoricus near Lavrio, the most ancient theatre in Greece.

If half-marathons are special enough for you, you might enjoy going there in October.